# Android Studio change color scheme

Tags: java, android-studio

As title,
I try to change color scheme.
Settings->Editor->Color&Font->Java.
But there is nothing change.
Version 2.1.2

Answer (score 1):

Please try this code :

**File->Settings->Editor->Colors & Fonts->** In scheme name select Darcula and **apply** to see a awesome dark background theme editor

Answer (score 0):

You can install plugins 
**File->Settings->Plugins->Browse Repositories->Search : Material Theme UI** and get restart your Android Studio and lets try change your scheme.

Answer (score 0):

Just try **File->Settings->Appearance & Behavior->Appearance->Theme**